# Error starting Nginx when customizing: SYSV error

Tags: nginx, system, nginx-reverse-proxy

I got an error when trying to customize nginx:

```
[root@test ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx (via systemctl):  Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@test ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-26 09:32:10 +07; 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5340 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx start (code=exited, status=5)

Oct 26 09:32:10 test systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server...
Oct 26 09:32:10 test systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=5
Oct 26 09:32:10 test systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server.
Oct 26 09:32:10 test systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Oct 26 09:32:10 test systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Here is my /etc/init.d/nginx file:

```
[root@test ~]# cat /etc/init.d/nginx
#!/bin/sh
#
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemon
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15
# description:  Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse \
#               proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
# processname: nginx
# config:      /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
# config:      /etc/sysconfig/nginx
# pidfile:     /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

NGINX_CONF_FILE="/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"

#[ -f /etc/sysconfig/nginx ] && . /etc/sysconfig/nginx

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/nginx

make_dirs() {
   # make required directories
   #user=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "configure arguments:" | sed 's/[^*]*--user=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g' -`
   #if [ -z "`grep $user /etc/passwd`" ]; then
   #    useradd -M -s /bin/nologin $user
   #fi
   options=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep 'configure arguments:'`
   for opt in $options; do
       if [ `echo $opt | grep '.*-temp-path'` ]; then
           value=`echo $opt | cut -d "=" -f 2`
           if [ ! -d "$value" ]; then
               # echo "creating" $value
               mkdir -p $value && chown -R $user $value
           fi
       fi
   done
}

start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    make_dirs
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -QUIT
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest || return $?
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc $nginx -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

configtest() {
  $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
            ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}"
        exit 2
esac
```

I tried booting but it didn't work, happy to help. Above are the configuration files and commands I have executed, the paths I have checked and are completely correct

I don't know what to do, I hope to receive your help. Thank